# How can i show pop up message when entered website?

Tags: jquery, shopify

I am working with shopify, this is the link of website, i am working. https://crap-3.myshopify.com/ ,

When we entered the website, in the index page, show some pop up message like "welcome to our website".

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myInput').focus()
  })




<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

May i know, how can i do this, any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can call the method on document.ready

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   $('#myModal').modal('show')
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Welcome Message</p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: still i am struggling

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(document).ready...` like:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
    // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
    alert("(document).ready was called - document is ready!");  
 });
```

OR

Giving a function to the `onLoad` property of body, which execute a JavaScript immediately after a page has been loaded:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

The `window.load` however will wait for the page to be fully loaded, this includes inner frames, images etc.

```
$(window).load(function() 
{
   // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
   alert("(window).load was called - window is loaded!");
});
```

`window.load` is a built-in JavaScript method, it is known to have some quirks in old browsers (IE6, IE8, old FF and Opera versions) but will generally work in all of them.

`window.load` can be used in the body's onload event like this.

Do not confuse the load method of the `window` element with the jQuery AJAX's load method!!!

```
// This is the AJAX load
$("#MyDivID").load("content_page.txt");
```

Here is a sample worked for me:

**html**:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Popup Box DIV </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="popup_box">    <!-- OUR PopupBox DIV-->
    <h1>This IS A Cool PopUp</h1>
    <a id="popupBoxClose">Close</a>    
</div>
<div id="container"> <!-- Main Page -->
    <h1>sample</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**css**:

```
<style type="text/css">
/* popup_box DIV-Styles*/
#popup_box { 
    display:none; /* Hide the DIV */
    position:fixed;  
    _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6 */  
    height:300px;  
    width:600px;  
    background:#FFFFFF;  
    left: 300px;
    top: 150px;
    z-index:100; /* Layering ( on-top of others), if you have lots of layers: I just maximized, you can change it yourself */
    margin-left: 15px;  

    /* additional features, can be omitted */
    border:2px solid #ff0000;      
    padding:15px;  
    font-size:15px;  
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;

}

#container {
    background: #d2d2d2; /*Sample*/
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

a{  
cursor: pointer;  
text-decoration:none;  
} 

/* This is for the positioning of the Close Link */
#popupBoxClose {
    font-size:20px;  
    line-height:15px;  
    right:5px;  
    top:5px;  
    position:absolute;  
    color:#6fa5e2;  
    font-weight:500;      
}
</style>
```

**js**:

```
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready( function() {

        // When site loaded, load the Popupbox First
        loadPopupBox();

        $('#popupBoxClose').click( function() {            
            unloadPopupBox();
        });

        $('#container').click( function() {
            unloadPopupBox();
        });

        function unloadPopupBox() {    // TO Unload the Popupbox
            $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
            $("#container").css({ // this is just for style        
                "opacity": "1"  
            }); 
        }    

        function loadPopupBox() {    // To Load the Popupbox
            $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
            $("#container").css({ // this is just for style
                "opacity": "0.3"  
            });         
        }        
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is a basic coding standard of javascript[jQuery]. I left this answer, hoping that you may do the rest on it. Now may be you have missed something for your purpose, or when naming it.

Comment: i need like this: http://imgur.com/CsomvzF but instead of subscribe, i need to show just message..

Comment: Sorry.. This content is blocked. .. for me. Give a try yourself, don't wait for someone else to do all your work.

-end